# When running bundle install, get a "fatal: destination...path already exists" error even if I delete the file that supposdely exists

Tags: rubygems, rvm, bundler

I am learning Sinatra from an online school and after cloning the lab, I am encountering an error that I can not figure out what to do with.

It seems to be related to the gem database_cleaner which is in my Gemfile.lock as:

> specs:
>       database_cleaner (1.5.1)

When I do a bundle install I get:

> fatal: destination path '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bundler/gems/database_cleaner-b87f00320f8a' already exists and is not an empty directory.

It also tells me:

> If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory               
>   '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/cache/bundler/git/database_cleaner-af6821d13d1b9
>   1b134663c2c8b73fe98bd8b0c80'

When I go and delete this file, and confirm that it has been deleted, I run bundle install again. I get the same error and the file is magically back.

The only solution I have found around this problem is to run bundle update, but of course this leads to many other problems with the lab.

Thank you in advance for any help or advice.

Comment: I know I'm a little late, but did you figure it out? One solution would be to update to `database_cleaner` version 1.5.3. Could you post your `Gemfile` if you still need help with this?